# Set filter as ALL

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using a user form that their inputs makes a filter function of two parameters: the dataframe and the filter definition.
Often I need ignore that filter, but I have to pass obligatorily for the user form. 
What is the fillments I can assign it to get ALL the rows of the dataframe?

```
> require (dplyr)
> a <- data.frame(f1 = 1:10, f2 = 11:12)
> filter_by_f2 <- function (a, filterlist) {
+   filter(a,f2 %in% filterlist)
+ }
> filterlist <- 11
> filter_by_f2 (a, filterlist)
  f1 f2
1  1 11
2  3 11
3  5 11
4  7 11
5  9 11
> # I would like set filter that get all the rows
> filterlist <- TRUE
> filter_by_f2 (a, filterlist)
[1] f1 f2
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
> # need this result when I filtered
> a
   f1 f2
1   1 11
2   2 12
3   3 11
4   4 12
5   5 11
6   6 12
7   7 11
8   8 12
9   9 11
10 10 12
```

Comment: It is not clear (at least to me) what you are asking.  Additionally `subset` is from base-R and not `dplyr`.  If you want to use filtering in `dplyr` the command is `filter()`

Comment: Why do you want to filter if you want to get all the rows? That's not filtering AFAIK ....

Comment: yes, Need this behavior, used a lot in webs when you search nothing, It returns all the contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TRUE` as a filter:

```
my_filter <- TRUE
a <- data.frame(f1 = 1:10, f2 = 11:12)
a <- subset(a, my_filter)
```

Alternative approach:

```
a <- data.frame(f1 = 1:10, f2 = 11:12)
filter_by_f2 <- function (a, filterlist) {
   filter(a,f2 %in% filterlist)
}

filter_by_f2(a, a$f2)
```

Comment: It is nice, but I need it over the field. I improve the question putting the filter action into a function. ¿do you know What imput needs the function to return all the rows? is It necessary modify the function ?

Comment: that works, but It seems greedy
`filterlist <- 1:10000000000`

Comment: thats what I need. is It avoid iteration?

Comment: Yes, there is no iteration in filter.

Answer (score 1):

You could have used the "not in" construction by prepending the logical operation with "!".

```
filter(a, !(f2 %in% NULL) )
   f1 f2
1   1 11
2   2 12
3   3 11
4   4 12
5   5 11
6   6 12
7   7 11
8   8 12
9   9 11
10 10 12
```